# LazyColumn displaying a list of custom composables (and a Coursera example solution) does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I am new to Android Development and I just wanted to implement a LazyColumn with some custom composable inside (while doing the Coursera Meta Android Development course). Unfortunately, every time I try to scroll the column list in the emulator the app stops. The same is true of the example "solution" provided by Coursera.

First I tried to implement the LazyColumn as specified by Coursera, that is:

I have a repository of elements of the data class Dish:

```
object DishRepository {
    val dishes = listOf(
        Dish(
            1,
            "Greek Salad",
            "The famous greek salad of crispy lettuce, peppers, olives, our Chicago.",
            12.99,
            R.drawable.greeksalad
        ),
        Dish(
            2, etc etc
```

then I have a MenuDish composable:

```
@Composable
fun MenuDish(id: Int, dish: Dish) {
    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)) {
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = dish.imageResource),
            contentDescription = "Dish image",
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth)
        Column (verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp)) {
            Text(
                text = dish.name,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = dish.description,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
            )

            
        }
    }
}}
```

and in an appropriate composable I did this:

```
LazyColumn {
            itemsIndexed(dishes) { _, dish ->
                MenuDish( dish)
            }
```

this crashes the app and produces the stack trace as below.

So I tried this:

```
LazyColumn {
            items(5000) {
                MenuDish( dish)
            }
```

passing only one single dish (say No 1 or No 2 or any other number) from the repository - this worked perfectly without any issues at all.

then I tried

```
LazyColumn {
            item{
                MenuDish( dish1)
            }
            item{
                MenuDish( dish2)
            }
            item{
                MenuDish( dish3)
            }
             etc etc
```

this again crashed the app when I tried scrolling the list.

Finally I downloaded the Coursera solution ([for anyone who can access - happy to send through email or whatever](https://www.coursera.org/learn/create-the-user-interface-android-studio/supplement/FqtE7/solution-code-create-an-app-ui)
which has the same issue - stopping when the list is scrolled.

I also tried creating my own project from scratch to avoid any issues of outdated libraries etc and writing the same code - the same problem appears - always with the same stack trace.

I'm using Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch 2

EDIT:

After more experiments and looking at the stack trace, it seems that he problem is, in fact, caused by two specific images:
the only distinguishing feature of these is that they have dimensions larger than the others (but not size as one of the images that display correctly
has 6MB - but is 4928x3263)
they are:
3.7MB - 6589x4395 and
12MB -  8256x5504

Unfortunately changing the way the images are displayed (as far as I can see) that is setting modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp) removing the fillWidth and/or fillMaxWidth, changing to fillHeight etc does not help and those two images produce the same exeption.

StackTrace:

```
 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.jan.testapp, PID: 7144
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(181764096bytes) bitmap.
                                                                                                        at android.graphics.RecordingCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(RecordingCanvas.java:266)
                                                                                                        at android.graphics.BaseRecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(BaseRecordingCanvas.java:94)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.AndroidCanvas.drawImageRect-HPBpro0(AndroidCanvas.android.kt:271)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.CanvasDrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs(CanvasDrawScope.kt:263)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs(Unknown Source:40)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs$default(DrawScope.kt:510)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.BitmapPainter.onDraw(BitmapPainter.kt:93)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter.draw-x_KDEd0(Painter.kt:212)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.draw.PainterNode.draw(PainterModifier.kt:342)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawDirect-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:105)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.draw-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:86)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:365)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:354)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:182)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:362)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:54)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:384)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:383)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2299)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:467)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:383)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:54)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeApi29.record(RenderNodeApi29.android.kt:209)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.updateDisplayList(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:305)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.drawLayer(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:246)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:349)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:182)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:362)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:354)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:182)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:362)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:354)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:922)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.performDraw(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:174)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:362)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:54)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:384)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:383)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2299)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:467)
2024-01-25 10:43:54.276  7144-7144  AndroidRuntime          com.jan.testapp                      E      at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:383)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:54)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeApi29.record(RenderNodeApi29.android.kt:209)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.updateDisplayList(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:305)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.drawLayer(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:246)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:349)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:922)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.performDraw(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:174)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawContent(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:66)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.DrawOverscrollModifier.draw(AndroidOverscroll.kt:79)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.draw(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:349)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawDirect-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:105)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.draw-x_KDEd0$ui_release(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:86)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:365)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.draw(NodeCoordinator.kt:354)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.performDraw(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:182)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:362)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(NodeCoordinator.kt:54)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:384)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$invoke$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:383)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2299)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:467)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:383)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:54)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeApi29.record(RenderNodeApi29.android.kt:209)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.updateDisplayList(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:305)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1138)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23892)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22756)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:694)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:700)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:798)
2024-01-25 10:43:54.277  7144-7144  AndroidRuntime          com.jan.testapp                      E      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4939)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:4643)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3822)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2465)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9305)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1339)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1348)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:952)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:882)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1322)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

Comment: If it crashes (e.g., you are seeing the app close), what is the stack trace?

Comment: and if you could elaborate on `this doesn't work.`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Sorry - just added the stack trace - it seems that the problem are 2 specific images in the composable in the list but I still can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are importing the correct dependencies:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
```

Then, try the following:

```kotlin
    LazyColumn {
        items(dishes) { dish ->
            MenuDish(dish)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the two images that are too large from the `drawable` folder into the `drawable-xxhdpi` folder and report back if that solves the issue.

The images contained in the `drawable` folder are interpreted to be medium resolution `drawable-mdpi`. These images will be scaled on high resolution screen accordingly. Now, if you put a high-resultion image in there and want to display it on a high-resolution screen, the image will be scaled up even more, resulting in a too big image. This could be happening in your case.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve it - the same exception for those two images. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Then you might have to reduce the size of these two images.